# Error while running Django Server -The empty path didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to develop a web app. When I run server, I get the below error message.

Error: Page not found (404)
Using the URLconf defined in Mywebsite_Website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
^admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Django is trying to route a path request to a defined URL in one of your urls.py files.

So far you only have two possible options set up with your urls.py files it seems:

- the Admin pages at: yoururl.com/admin/
- the Index page at: yoururl.com/

The URL that you tried to go to does not fall into either of those categories. Out in the wild this would result in a 404 Page Not Found Error.